# Assigning one property to another inside jQuery Object Literal

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm refactoring existing working code in jQuery into jQuery plugin. In the original code, I have several variables which I use to store settings. One of which is referenced in the other:

```
var className = ".container";
var element   = `<div class="${className.slice(1)}"></div>`;
```

In the plugin code I'm trying to do the same, but inside Object Literal and I'm getting undefined when I reference "className":

```
$.fn.pluginName = function (options) {

    var defaultSettings = {
        className: ".container",
        element:  function() {
            return `<div class="${this.className.slice(1)}"></div>`;
        };
    };

    var settings = $.extend({}, defaultSettings, options);
};
```

Comment: How is `element` being invoked?

Comment: Why not replace `this` with `defaultSettings`?

Comment: @NickParsons later I will inject this element based on a click event.

Comment: `this` inside of a `function` is determined based on how the function is called. That's why I'm asking how the `element` function is called... if you can't control that then a simpler solution is to not use `this` at all and use `defaultSettings` directly as trincot suggests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you've said you don't control how the `element` function is called, you can't rely on `this` within it (unless you use `bind`, but there's no need here).

I'm assuming `options` can override `defaultSettings.className`, so you don't just want to use `defaultSettings` instead of `this`.

You can use `settings`, though:

```
$.fn.pluginName = function (options) {
    const defaultSettings = {
        className: ".container",
        element: () => {
            return `<div class="${settings.className.slice(1)}"></div>`;
        },
    };
    const settings = Object.assign({}, defaultSettings, options);
    // ...presumably more code here...
};
```

Even though it's above `const settings` in the code, it won't be *called* until after `settings` has been initialized with a value.

Comment: Yes option will overwrite defaultSettings. I'm wondering what is the difference between $.extend and Object.assign?

Comment: @BozhidarGeorgiev - There isn't a significant difference in this case since you weren't using `true` as the first argument, it's just that `Object.assign` is built-in and `$.extend` is provided by jQuery. (JavaScript's standard library didn't have `Object.assign` when jQuery was created, so Resig provided it for situations just like this.) If you were using `true` as the first argument to `$.extend` to get a deep merge, that would be a big difference, since `Object.assign` doesn't support deep merge. :-)